# Is there a way to lock a VScode split-window's width?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't like all my windows to constantly re-arrange and re-size every time I open or close a split. In particular, I don't want my "Terminal" windows to *ever* be zoomed up to 200 columns wide; in fact, I prefer them to stay at precisely 105 columns wide, and for all other windows to share any remaining space.

Is there a way for me to say "when automatically re-arranging window-panes, please keep *this* vertical-split at exactly 105 columns wide?"

(For reference, I'm talking about the behaviour of Vim's [`:set winfixwidth`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27winfixwidth%27).)

Comment: this would be so useful ...